# Remove picture in EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus

Using EPlus, how do you remove an exiting picture from a worksheet?  I don't see a "Remove" method on the Drawings collection.

Answer (score 1):

ExcelDrawings has a Remove method:

Example: sheet.Drawings.Remove("image1");

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Removes a drawing.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   Drawing:
    //     The drawing
    public void Remove(ExcelDrawing Drawing);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Removes a drawing.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   Index:
    //     The index of the drawing
    public void Remove(int Index);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Removes a drawing.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   Name:
    //     The name of the drawing
    public void Remove(string Name);
```